# Laravel/Composer: adding seeds programmatically

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.1

Currently I'm trying to develope a package update system with the following workflow.
I'm creating a package (.zip) with the following files:

- migrations (folder)

  - migrationClass
  - ..
- seeds

  - seedfile
  - ..
- package.xml
- UpdateInstructionSeeder.php

As a administrator I can upload this package in my admin control panel to update my database.

backend workflow:

1. get data from package.xml (get available seeds and migrations)
2. check if a migration/seeding is needed
3. migrate (works fine)
4. seed (fails)

So, as you can see I have some trouble with my seeding.

At first I tried to move (with `Storage::move()`) my seeds from the package seed folder to the `database/seed/` directory. 
I tried to seed it with `Artisan::call('db:seed','--class']);` but a `Class MyClass does not exist` error appeared. 
I guessed that there are some problems with my autoloader, so I've tried to dump it with `system('composer dump-autoload', $test);`. The output of `$test` was `1` but the `autoload_classmap` wasn't updated.

Now I've added a `UpdateInstructionSeeder.php` which is available in my framework by default to fix the autoloader problem.
After uploading my package, I'm using now `Storage::get()` and `Storage::put()` to update this with my needed seeds.

Then I'm adding seeds with `Artisan::call('make:seeder', ['name' => $className]);` ($className is the name of my seeds from the package) and update them with `Storage::get()` and `Storage::put()`, too.

Finally I'm calling my seeder with `Artisan::call('db:seed','--class' => 'UpdateInstructionSeeder']);`. Result: 
`Class MyClass does not exist`

Content:

**package UpdateInstructionSeeder**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UpdateInstructionSeeder extends Seeder
{
   /**
    * Run the database seeds.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function run()
   {
       Model::unguard();

       $this->call(DemoTableSeeder::class);

       Model::reguard();
   }
}
```

**package DemoTableSeeder**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DemoTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        DB::table('demos')->insert([
            [
                'demoInt' => 1,
                'demoString' => "a"
            ],
            [
                'demoInt' => 11,
                'demoString' => "aa"
            ],
        ]);

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

I wasted now a lot of hours and I have absolutely no idea to solve this problem *programatically*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan cache:clear 
chmod -R guo+w storage
composer dump-autoload
```

Then finally

```
php artisan db:seed
```

You can call all those command programmatically using Artisan::call like below

```
Artisan::call('optimize', ['--quiet' => true, '--force' => true]);
```

EDIT

Make one `.sh` file with following contents and run it using php

optimize.sh

---

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan cache:clear 
chmod -R guo+w storage
composer dump-autoload
```

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/ssh

Comment: Like this? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3baece51cf7211fce80dcb899a230542
It doesn't work :( But to be honest: I've copied the exec()-part from the internet. Is this the correct way to dump the autoloader?

Comment: You can make one .sh file and put all those command and then can run .sh file programatically